# How do I achieve automatic numbering for headings using css

Tags: html, css

Could you please help me out to represent my 'Heading Title' and 'Subheading Title' with automatic numbering using css. As i need to have headings only with h1,h2 and not with ol,ul,li...

Here is my code:

```
<style>
h1,h2 {  display: list-item; list-style-position: inside; }
</style>


    <div id="page">
      <h1>Heading Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
      <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
      <h1>Heading Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
      <h1>Heading Title</h1>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please show what have you tried so far? how much research have you done. please add your css as well

Comment: @Lucian i have added my css that i have tried it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could you please try this it will help you.

```css
#page {
 counter-reset: heading;
}
h1:before {
 content: counter(heading)") ";
 counter-increment: heading;
}
h1 {
 counter-reset: subheading;
}
h2:before {
 content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheading)") ";
 counter-increment: subheading;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <h1>Heading Title</h1>
  <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
  <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
  <h1>Heading Title</h1>
  <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
  <h1>Heading Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. you need to define your parent div as `<ol>` and it's child as `<li>`

```css
#page {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: newCounter;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
#page > .top-list h1 {
  display: list-item;
}
#page > .top-list h1:before {
  counter-increment: newCounter;
  content: counters(newCounter, ".")" ";
}
.inner {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: newCounter;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.inner > h2 {
  display: list-item;
}
.inner > h2:before {
  counter-increment: newCounter;
  content: counters(newCounter, ".")" ";
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="top-list">
    <h1>Heading Title</h1>
    <div class="inner">
      <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
      <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-list">
    <h1>Heading Title</h1>
    <div class="inner">
      <h2>Subheading Title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-list">
    <h1>Heading Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As your are almost near but as headings H1 with 1 and its subheadings with 1.1,1.2...

Comment: oh. so you need h2 as subheadings? then you will need to wrap those with another div

Comment: always a pleasure :)